# flight php controller class

Tags: php, controller, router

i have this controller class

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Application\Controller;
use Application\FlightApplication;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function test(){
       $this->app->logger->debug('test');
       echo 'test';
    }

}
```

that extends this class

```
<?php

namespace Application;

class Controller {

    public $app = null;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->app = FlightApplication::getInstance();
    }

}
```

when i run this route:

```
Flight::route('/test', array('App\Controllers\TestController','test'));
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

why?

this is `FlightApplication` class                     :

```
<?php

namespace Application;

class FlightApplication {

private static $instance = null;

public function __construct(){
    self::$instance = $this;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return \Application\FlightApplication
 */
public static function getInstance(){
    return self::$instance;
}

public function start(){
    \Flight::start();
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `FlightApplication::getInstance()` does not return `null`?

Comment: Without the `FlightApplication` class I'm not sure we can answer this

Comment: FlightApplication does not return null. I have updated answer whit the source of class

Comment: Is that some kind of "Singleton"? `FlightApplication::getInstance()` will return null unless you don't init it somewhere with `new FlightApplication` Please, can you do `var_dump($this->app)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your Singleton is wrong. You never instantiate your class so the get function always returns `NULL`. You need to have a check to instantiate the class

```
public static function getInstance(){
    if(!self::$instance) self::$instance = new self();
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Additionally you should take the setting out of your constructor

```
public function __construct(){
    self::$instance = $this; // Remove this line as your Singleton handles this
}
```